# How to install tensorflow-gpu 1.15 on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, installation, pip

The documentation here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Indicates I need to run

`https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu`

but when I try that on Ubuntu linux 20.04, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15
```

I really need that specific version... how can I get it installed?

Thanks,

Comment: Most probably because you are using Python 3.8, and 1.15 is compiled only for 3.5/3.6/3.7.

Comment: As there are no download files for `TF1.15` with `cp38(i.e python 3.8)` on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.0/#files).Thanks!